# How to restrict one url to only one view in django urls

Tags: python, r, url, python-2.7, django-1.4

I am facing problem in urls.My project name is Stock and my app name is Stock_app,

Stock urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^goc/', include('stock_app.urls')),
  url(r'^goc_range/', include('stock_app.urls')),
)
```

in my stock_app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('stock_app.views',

   url(r'^(\w+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc'),
   url(r'^(\w+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc_range'),
)
```

i am facing a problem,here whenever user visits goc/ and goc_range/ both are having access to both the urls in stock_app.urls ,

i mean goc/  is for goc function, goc_range/ is for goc_range function.

i want like follwoing access

goc/ --> go for only url(r'^(\w+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc'),
goc_range/ --> go for only url(r'^(\w+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc_range'),

whenever user gives goc/name/date he must go to only url(r'^(\w+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc'),
and also goc_range/name/date/date he must go to only  url(r'^(\w+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc_range'),

help me

Comment: Put the `goc_range` pattern above the `goc` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL patterns are not correct, change the patterns in Stock urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^', include('stock_app.urls')),
)
```

and stock_app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('stock_app.views',
   url(r'^goc/(\w+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc'),
   url(r'^goc_range/(\w+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', 'goc_range'),
)
```

Basically the the main patterns file includes the patterns from the second file, so they are only required once.

Comment: Thanks ! Tim, it worked. I forgotten this by thinking too much.